# spaces in ffmpeg bash script filename variables

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, naming-conventions, spaces

I am using OS X Yosemite. I want to make a simple bash script that allows me to transcode a video. Everything works well as long as a file is not located in a directory which has spaces.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ffmpeg -i “$1” -c:v ffv1 -level 3 -g 1 -c:a copy “$1.mkv”
```

Initially, I did not have the double quotes around the variable, but I read some stack overflows that used this as a solution. I'd rather not have to alter the path or add slashes etc. I want to just run:

```
 ./script.sh filename.mov
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Kierans-iMac:~ bla$ ./firstscript.command "/Users/bla/Desktop/untitled\ folder\ 2/v210.mov.mkv" 
ffmpeg version 2.7.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.7.2_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfaac --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.2_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 ' --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
“/Users/bla/Desktop/untitled\: No such file or directory
```

Comment: your actual cmd is `./firstscript.command "/Users/bla/Desktop/untitled\ folder\ 2/v210.mov.mkv"` . A path is a path, either you `cd` to the dir and execute from there, or you have to pass the path (full or relative) in your command. As you have already dbl-quoted your path try removing the 2 `'\'` chars escaping the spaces. OR eliminate a whole class of error from using a unix derived systems and don't use spaces in dir or filenames ;-! Good luck.

Comment: Are you using proper ASCII double quotes, or the curly quotes shown in this question?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I just used script.sh as a generic example. I removed the double quotes from the path, so now it's ./firstscript.command /Users/bla/Desktop/untitled\ folder\ 2/v210.mov.mkv but it's the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quoting the spaces twice:

```
./firstscript.command "/Users/bla/Desktop/untitled\ folder\ 2/v210.mov.mkv"
```

should just be

```
./firstscript.command "/Users/bla/Desktop/untitled folder 2/v210.mov.mkv"
```

A quoted string `"foo"` is equivalent to `\f\o\o`; every character is escaped. The backslashes in your original are treated as literal backslashes.

Inside the script, you still need to quote the parameter expansion:

```
ffmpeg -i "$1" -c:v ffv1 -level 3 -g 1 -c:a copy "$1.mkv"
```

Note that you have to use regular ASCII quotes (`"`), not the "smart" quotes (`“`) implied by the error message in your link.

Comment: Thanks! I did indeed have those smart quotes in my script. When I enabled the ascii quotes, the script worked! Actually, i didn't even need to  put the quotes around the command in terminal. Hopefully I won't have to, as it seemed to work just fine with no quotes?

Comment: Right; `"foo bar"` and `foo\ bar` are identical strings after the shell performs quote removal